# iOS designable UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibdesignable

I was trying to use the IBDesignable within my projects.

Could somebody help me to find out how to make work this class?

[APTextField.swift on gitHub](https://github.com/tylyo/APDesignableControls/blob/master/APTextField.swift)

Comment: you could be able to test it easily by yourself! it was a file you can include in an empty project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this code

```
 required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
```

and if you are using Xcode 6.3 (6D520o) replace **countElements** func with **count**